# Issue fetching data from DataStore, but using Shared preferences everything works

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit2, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-datastore

My problem is that when using DataStore, the data is saved correctly and updated correctly every time, but it is read incorrectly. ( I open applicationB from applicationA and I am passing data with intent) When I launch the application for the first time, I do not have access to the data I wanted to transfer. Only when the application is relaunched, the data is returned from the DataStore, but it is old data.

This problem does not occur when using SharedPreferences.

I assume it's Dagger's fault because the DataStore and SharedPreferences write the data correctly, but the DataStore can't read it fast enough. DataStore is a relatively new library, so maybe this isn't handled correctly.

I've tried to restrict the scope so I've added `@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)` but it didn't work. I've tried fetching the data about ipAdress in Application() class, but it didn't work either

Below is my RetrofitModule in which I try to get **ipAddress** from DataStore:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class RetrofitModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideNetworkJson(): Json = Json {
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofitApi(
        networkJson: Json,
        dataStore: PreferencesDataSource
    ): RetrofitApi {
        val refreshTokenInterceptor = createRefreshTokenInterceptor(dataStore)

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(createUrl(dataStore))
            .addConverterFactory(
                networkJson.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType())
            )
            .client(okHttpClient(refreshTokenInterceptor))
            .build()
            .create(RetrofitApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePlanogramApi(
        networkJson: Json,
        dataStore: PreferencesDataSource
    ): PlanogramApi {
        val refreshTokenInterceptor = createRefreshTokenInterceptor(dataStore)

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.PLANOGRAM_BACKEND_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(
                networkJson.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType())
            )
            .client(okHttpClient(refreshTokenInterceptor))
            .build()
            .create(PlanogramApi::class.java)
    }

    private fun okHttpClient(refreshTokenInterceptor: Interceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(refreshTokenInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                if (shouldLog()) {
                    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                }
            })
            .build()
    }

    private fun createRefreshTokenInterceptor(dataStore: PreferencesDataSource): Interceptor {
        return Interceptor { chain ->
            val originalRequest = chain.request()
            val refreshToken = runBlocking {
                dataStore.userData.firstOrNull()?.token
            }
            val modifiedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer $refreshToken")
                .build()
            chain.proceed(modifiedRequest)
        }
    }

    private fun shouldLog(): Boolean {
        return when (BuildConfig.FLAVOR) {
            "prod" -> false
            else -> true
        }
    }

    private fun createUrl(dataStore: PreferencesDataSource): String {
        val ipAddress = runBlocking {
            dataStore.userData.firstOrNull()?.serverIp
        }
        return when (ipAddress) {
            "" -> String.format(SERVER_URL_TEMPLATE, BuildConfig.BACKEND_URL)
            else -> String.format(SERVER_URL_TEMPLATE, ipAddress)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val SERVER_URL_TEMPLATE = "http://%s:1010"
    }


}
```

DataStore Module:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DataStoreModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserPreferencesSerializer() : UserPreferencesSerializer {
        return UserPreferencesSerializer()
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserPreferencesDataStore(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        @Dispatcher(IO) ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
        @ApplicationScope scope: CoroutineScope,
        userPreferencesSerializer: UserPreferencesSerializer,
    ) : DataStore<UserData> =
        DataStoreFactory.create(
            serializer = userPreferencesSerializer,
            scope = CoroutineScope(scope.coroutineContext + ioDispatcher)
        ) {
            context.dataStoreFile("user_preferences.json")
        }
}
```